# INSERT INTO a table - SELECT doesn't bring back all records but SUM brings back correct answer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert

I have been looking at inserting rows into a SQL table and have created the test  code below

---

```
DECLARE @ItemSale TABLE (ID INT, Qty INT, Price INT)

INSERT INTO @ItemSale (ID, Qty, Price) 
    VALUES (1, 25, 100) 
INSERT INTO @ItemSale (ID, Qty, Price) 
    VALUES (2, 4, 200)   
INSERT INTO @ItemSale (ID, Qty, Price) 
    VALUES (3, 5, 300)

SELECT 
    *
    --SUM(Price)
FROM 
    @ItemSale
```

---

I am only getting the first row back

```
ID  Qty Price
1   25  100
```

When I comment in the SUM(Price) (and comment out the *) I get

```
SUM
600
```

which is what I expect
Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your code should be returning all the rows.  This might be an issue with the interface software you are using.

Comment: Assuming t-sql that will return 3 rows as you expect, what are you using to execute the query?

Comment: I just tested the code. It returned 3 rows.

Comment: I am assuming this is SQL Server based on the syntax. The only way I was able to replicate this behaviour is by running `SET ROWCOUNT 1;` first. Maybe try again after running `SET ROWCOUNT 0;`

Comment: Thank you
Running SET ROWCOUNT 0 first returns
ID Qty Price
1 25 100
2 4 200
3 5 300

as expected

Answer (score 0):

SET NOCOUNT ON might help in this situation.